# I need to create a simple module in drupal 7 to display “Hello world”

Tags: php, content-management-system, drupal-7

I need to create a simple module in drupal 7 to display “Hello world” which can locate in various regions like content, header, footer, etc. and after reading a couple of tutorials, i can’t seem to display anything appropriate.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/778734

Comment: i have already seen the link before,but it doesn't show how to locate the module to a region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new block. You can do that with following hooks: [`hook_block_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [`hook_block_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7).

Create a new directory and call it `hello_world`. Create a `hello_world.info` and `hello_world.module` file.

You put following stuff in the `hello_world.info` file:

```
name = Hello World
description = Small module which just provides a block.
core = 7.x
```

And following into `hello_world.module`:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Main file of Hello World module.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function hello_world_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['hello_world'] = array(
    'info' => t('Hello world'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function hello_world_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  if ($delta == 'hello_world') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Hello world');
    $block['content'] = t('This is the block content.');
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Then put the `hello_world` directory into `sites/all/modules/custom` and enable the module on `/admin/modules`. You will see a new block called "Hello world" in the block overview (`/admin/structure/block`). Drag it into the right region and the block will show up there.